# Probability of D4 rolling a previously appearing number

Tags: probability, dice

Four fair dice D1, D2, D3 and D4, each having six faces numbered $1$ through $6$, are rolled simultaneously. What is the probability that D4 shows a number appearing on one of D1, D2, or D3?

My approach:

**Case 1:**

Let all the three dice give the same output:

$$\frac{6}{6}\text{ (any number comes on first)}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{6}.$$

**Case 2:**

Let two be the same:

$$^3C_1\times\frac{6}{6}\times{}^2C_1\times\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{5}{6}\times{}^2C_1\times\frac{1}{6}.$$

**Case 3:**

Let all three be different:

$$\frac{6}{6}\times\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}\times{}^3C_1\times\frac{1}{6}.$$

Adding, we get $\frac{91}{216}$, which is the correct answer. Is my method correct, and is there any other simpler method?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251576/probability-of-d-4

Comment: This is a bit of coincident that the same question was asked just 20 hrs ago. Well, thanks I should have searched the same before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint for an easier solution:

The event that $D_4$ shows a number that is **not** on $D_1,D_2,D_3$ can also be described as the event that $D_1,D_2,D_3$ show a number that differs from the number on $D_4$.

Comment: I must say, "whoa!", atleast for me. Now I will think about all the complementary cases every time! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.